# How to reduce 3d integer array to 2 dimensions?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, max, grouping

I have a 3d integer array and I want to reduce it to 2 dimensions by calculating the maximum along the third dimension.

I'm essentially looking for `numpy.amax(array, axis=3)` in java. I have also tried implementing this functionality myself, but my code is very slow. Does anyone know how to do this operation efficiently in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over this 3d array, where each element is a 2d array ⇒ iterate over 2d arrays, where each element is a 1d array ⇒ and get maximun value of 1d array. For this purpose you can use [`Stream.max(Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max(java.util.Comparator)) method:

```java
Integer[][][] arr3d = {
        {{10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18}},
        {{19, 20, 21}, {22, 23, 24}, {25, 26, 27}},
        {{28, 29, 30}, {31, 32, 33}, {34, 35, 36}}};
```

```java
Integer[][] result = Arrays.stream(arr3d).map(arr2d ->
        Arrays.stream(arr2d).map(arr1d ->
                Arrays.stream(arr1d)
                        .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::intValue))
                        .orElse(null))
                .toArray(Integer[]::new))
        .toArray(Integer[][]::new);
```

```java
Arrays.stream(result).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
// [12, 15, 18]
// [21, 24, 27]
// [30, 33, 36]
```

---

Or if you have a 3d array of primitives `int[][][]`, you can use [`IntStream.max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#max()) method:

```java
int[][] result = Arrays.stream(arr3d).map(arr2d ->
        Arrays.stream(arr2d).mapToInt(arr1d ->
                Arrays.stream(arr1d)
                        .max()
                        .orElse(0))
                .toArray())
        .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

---

<sup>See also: [Finding the largest number in an array using predefined java methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65461499/14838237)</sup>