# Compilation problem in Java program to find the largest value in an array

Tags: java, arrays, variables, scope, max

Here is the code snippet that I am working on and my goal is to find the largest value from the list using predefined Java methods.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a list of integers: ");
        int array[] = new int[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = s.nextInt();
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (j < array.length) {
                int maximum = Math.max(array[j], array[j + 1]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Largest number of the list: " + maximum);
    }
}
```

The error that I am getting is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
        maximum cannot be resolved to a variable
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You may just iterate the array of numbers and keep track of the largest value seen:

```java
int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

for (int j=0; j < array.length; j++) {
    if (array[j] > largest) {
        largest = array[j];
    }
}
```

Note: The above snippet assumes that you have at least one number in the input array.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining your **maximum** variable inside the for loop block, making it a local variable, then you're trying to access the value on this variable outside of its definition block, that is why Java cannot find such variable, because it does not exist on that scope. Try This:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a list of integers: ");
        int array[] = new int[10];
        int maximum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = s.nextInt();
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (j < array.length) {
                maximum = Math.max(array[j], array[j + 1]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Largest number of the list: " + maximum);
    }
}
```

Try reading [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/) for a further explanation on scopes and variables.

Answer (score 0):

As said above, pay attention to the variables scope:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a list of integers: ");

        int array[] = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = s.nextInt();
        }

        int maximum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
            maximum = Math.max(array[j], array[j + 1]);
        }

        System.out.println("Largest number of the list: " + maximum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [`IntStream.max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#max--) method to find the maximum element of a stream of `int` primitives:

   ```java
   int[] arr = {4, 7, 5, 3, 2, 9, 2, 7, 6, 7};

   int max = Arrays.stream(arr).max().getAsInt();

   System.out.println(max); // 9
   ```
2. You can use [`Stream.max(Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) method to find the maximum element of a stream of `Integer` objects:

   ```java
   List<Integer> list =
           Arrays.asList(6, 10, 2, 1, 6, 4, 5, 8, 9, 8);

   Integer max2 = list.stream()
           .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::intValue))
           .get();

   System.out.println(max2); // 10
   ```

---

<sup>See also:

• [How to find first 5 highest value in a two dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65376850/14838237)

• [Selection sort of array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65351884/14838237)</sup>