# How to find first 5 highest value in a two dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, max

I have a two dimensional integer array. Row and Column information (locations of numbers) is important for me. So, I don't want to sort an array (matrix actually). How can I find the highest 5 value from this two dimensional array?

Here is my code:

```
for (int row = 0; row < matirx.length; row++) {
  for (int col = 0; col < matirx[row].length; col++) {
    if (matirx[row][col] > maxValue) {
      maxValue = matirx[row][col];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Let `MAX_N = 5`.
2. Find `count` as the total number of elements in `matrix[][]`.
3. Create `flattened = new int[count]` and fill it with all elements of `matrix[][]`.
4. Create max = new int[MAX_N] to store maximum n numbers. Also, create maxPos = new int[MAX_N] to store the position of the maximum numbers.
5. Loop `MAX_N` times and in each iteration, assume `flattened[0]` is the largest number.
6. If `flattened[j] >= max[i]`, check if the position, `j` has already been processed. If not assign `flattened[j]` to `max[i]` and `j` to `maxPos[i]`.

**Demo:**

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int MAX_N = 5;
        int[][] matrix = {
                {16, -20, 11, 19},
                {2, 5, 6, 8},
                {17, 25, 16, 19},
                {7, 17, 4, 17}};

        // Find count as the total number of elements
        int count = 0, row, col;
        for (row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            count += matrix[row].length;
        }

        // Create flattened = new int[count] and
        // fill it with all elements of matrix[][]
        int[] flattened = new int[count];
        int i = 0;
        for (row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
                flattened[i++] = matrix[row][col];
            }
        }

        // Create max = new int[MAX_N] to store maximum 
        // n numbers. Also, create maxPos = new int[MAX_N]
        // to store the position of the maximum numbers.
        int[] max = new int[MAX_N];
        int[] maxPos = new int[MAX_N];

        // Loop MAX_N times. In each iteration,
        // assume flattened[0] is the largest number.
        for (i = 0; i < max.length; i++) {
            max[i] = flattened[0];

            for (int j = 1; j < flattened.length; j++) {
                // If flattened[j] >= max[i], check if the
                // position, j has already been processed.
                // If not assign flattened[j] to max[i]
                // and j to maxPos[i].
                if (flattened[j] >= max[i]) {
                    boolean posAlreadyProcessed = false;
                    for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
                        if (maxPos[k] == j) {
                            posAlreadyProcessed = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!posAlreadyProcessed) {
                        max[i] = flattened[j];
                        maxPos[i] = j;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Largest " + MAX_N +
                " values: " + Arrays.toString(max));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Largest 5 values: [25, 19, 19, 17, 17]
```

Comment: This algorithm must iterate over the entire matrix five times. You could also fill your `int[] max` with `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, iterate over the matrix once, and replace the smallest entry of `max` each time the current integer is greater.

Comment: @MichaelChatiskatzi - An alternative solution can be a great idea. How about you doing it in https://ideone.com and posting the link?

Comment: I had something like this in mind: https://ideone.com/sm6xY6. I do not really like to update the array with the `Arrays.sort()` operation but I just could not think of something else that is that easy and requires similarly few lines.

Comment: Nice answer, but from what I can tell, it seems the OP cares about the locations of the values. Or maybe not, I'm unsure.

Comment: Thanks, @cigien for encouraging words. Let's wait for the OP's response. Generally, after this much time, an OP confirms whether the solution met their requirement or not.

Comment: @MichaelChatiskatzi - The OP has mentioned: `I don't want to sort array(matrix actually).`

Comment: I think OP wanted the actual matrix not to be modified. Which is quite understandable and should be the default. What I do is sort the array with the highest numbers. There is no loss of information by doing this. If OP is not allowed to use `Arrays.sort()` in principle, I agree with you of course.

Comment: I ran your solution on this matrix `{{16, -20, 11, 19},{2, 5, 6, 8},{17, 25, 16, 19},{7, 17, 4, 17}}`. I expected it to give me `[25, 19, 19, 17, 17]`, but it gave me `[25, 19, 17, 16, 16]`

Comment: @Scratte - Thanks for pointing it out. I've rectified the issue now.

Answer (score 7):

First, I went for a streams solution that is very similar to other Answers. I didn't like the boxing and unboxing variations, but since `IntStream` doesn't have a fancy method that makes sorting with a `Comparator` straight out of the box, the `IntStream` has to be converted into a `Stream` in order to sort the values in reverse order. I didn't think it was important to return an `int[]` array, since we're only really interested in the values.

```java
public static Integer[] streamIt(int[][] matrix, int n){
  Integer[] result = 
    Arrays.stream(matrix)                                         // stream the arrays
          // This is the same as using .flatMaptoInt(..) and then .boxed()
          .flatMap(a -> Arrays.stream(a)                          // stream the array in arrays
                              .mapToObj(i -> Integer.valueOf(i))) // turn the ints into Integers
          .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())                      // sort by higest values
          .limit(n)                                               // only pick n
          .toArray(i -> new Integer[i]);                          // put then in Integer array
  return result;
}
```

If you want them in an `int[]` array instead, look at the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65376850/12695027) by [shadow.sabre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14838237/shadow-sabre) that uses `mapToInt()` do to that.

---

While the streams solution is very neat and clean looking, I felt that the problem was really just to get the set of highest values, so inserting them into a standard java sorted `Set` made sense to me. I start off by inserting the values into the set until there are 5 elements in there. Then I check to see if the new value is higher than the lowest value, and if so, I just remove the lowest value while inserting the new one. Finding the lowest value is easy when using `TreeSet` as it's a sorted set.

The trick is to also check that the new value isn't already in the set. If there's already 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 in the set, and the new value is 5, then I don't want to remove the lowest value 1, since adding the new value wouldn't actually add any new elements to the Set. Remember a `Set` cannot contain duplicate values:

```java
public static Set<Integer> useSet(int[][] matrix, int n){
  TreeSet<Integer> max = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.<Integer>naturalOrder().reversed());
  for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
      // Keep adding values until there's n elements in the Set
      if (max.size() < n) { 
        max.add(matrix[i][j]);
      } else {
        // if the new value is higher than the lowest value
        //  ..and the new values isn't already there.
        if (max.last() < matrix[i][j] && !max.contains(matrix[i][j])) {
          max.pollLast();
          max.add(matrix[i][j]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return max;
}
```

Note that this solution obviously never contains the same values, but always the top distinct ones.

---

Looking at the set solution it was easy to add the additional functionality of keeping track of where in the matrix the values were found. I created a class, `Element`, to contain the value and its location. Every element in the matrix that's to be inserted into the `TreeSet` is created as an `Element`.

The `Element` needs to either `implement Comparable` or the `TreeSet` has to be initialized with a `Comparator` in order to sort the elements. This example of `Element` has both, and I just used the `static Comparator` in the implementation of `compareTo(Element that)` to make it a `Comparable<Element>`. Normally you'd implement the class with private fields using getters to fetch the values, but for this purpose is seemed a little verbose. Making the fields `final` also ensures the class is immutable so I have no scruples about it.

Since the comparison is done using both the value and the location, every element from the matrix will be distinct:

```java
class Element implements Comparable<Element> {
  final int value;
  final int x;
  final int y;

  static Comparator<Element> comparator = 
    Comparator.comparing((Element e) -> e.value)
              .thenComparing((Element e) -> e.x)
              .thenComparing((Element e) -> e.y)
              .reversed();

  Element(int value, int x, int y) {
    this.value = value;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  public int compareTo(Element that){
    return comparator.compare(this, that);
  }

  public String toString(){
    return value + " at [" + x + "][" + y + "]";
  }
}
```

If the `Element` didn't implement the `Comparable` interface, this would be the initialization of the `TreeSet`:

`TreeSet<Element> maxElement = new TreeSet<>(Element.comparator);`

But since `Element` does implement the `Comparable` interface, the set implementation can be initialized without it:

```java
public static Set<Element> useSetElements(int[][] matrix, int n){
  TreeSet<Element> maxElement = new TreeSet<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
      if (maxElement.size() < n) {
        maxElement.add(new Element(matrix[i][j],i,j));
      } else {
        if (maxElement.last().value < matrix[i][j]) {
          maxElement.pollLast();
          maxElement.add(new Element(matrix[i][j],i,j));
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return maxElement;
}
```

Note that because every element is distinct, there's no need to also check that the new value isn't already in the set.

---

Running the three solutions with given input:

```java
int n = 5;
int[][] matrix = {{16, -20, 22, 19}, 
                  { 2,   5,  6,  8},
                  {17,  25, 16, 19},
                  { 7,  18,  4, 17}};

System.out.println("streamIt: \n "
                   + Arrays.toString(streamIt(matrix,n)));
System.out.println("useSet: \n "
                   + useSet(matrix,n));
System.out.println("useSetElements: \n "
                   + useSetElements(matrix,n));
```

..gives this:

```java
streamIt:
 [25, 22, 19, 19, 18]
useSet:
 [25, 22, 19, 18, 17]
useSetElements:
 [25 at [2][1], 22 at [0][2], 19 at [2][3], 19 at [0][3], 18 at [3][1]]
```

### But what about Performance..?

The three different implementations had me wondering about the performance, so I added a method to time the execution:

```java
static void timeMethod(Runnable toRun){
  long start = System.nanoTime();
  try{
    toRun.run();
  } finally {
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("  Time: " + (end - start)/1.0e6 + " miliseconds");
  }
}
```

And ran the three solutions:

```
timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("streamIt: \n "
                                    + Arrays.toString(streamIt(matrix,n))));
timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("useSet: \n "
                                    + useSet(matrix,n)));
timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("useSetElements: \n "
                                    + useSetElements(matrix,n)));
```

..giving this result:

```
streamIt:
 [25, 22, 19, 19, 18]
  Time: 1.2759 miliseconds
useSet:
 [25, 22, 19, 18, 17]
  Time: 0.9343 miliseconds
useSetElements:
 [25 at [2][1], 22 at [0][2], 19 at [2][3], 19 at [0][3], 18 at [3][1]]
  Time: 1.16 miliseconds
```

It *seems* that the three solutions have roughly the same performance. The streams solution seems slightly slower. The `Set` solution looks promising, expect the solution using `Element` seems to take a toll. But to look at it more deeply I decided to run them on a much larger matrix, which I build using random integers:

```java
Random random = new Random();
int[][] largerMatrix =
  IntStream.range(0,10000)                     // 10000 on the first dimension
           .mapToObj(i -> random.ints(0,128)   // values between 0 and 128 (not included)
                                .limit(10000)  // 10000 on the second dimension
                                .toArray())    // make the second 1D arrays
           .toArray(int[][]::new);             // put them into a 2D array
```

Running the test with a 10000 by 10000 matrix:

```java
timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("streamIt: \n "
                                    + Arrays.toString(streamIt(largerMatrix,n))));
timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("useSet: \n "
                                    + useSet(largerMatrix,n)));
timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("useSetElements: \n "
                                    + useSetElements(largerMatrix,n)));
```

..gave this result:

```java
streamIt:
 [127, 127, 127, 127, 127]
  Time: 90374.6995 miliseconds
useSet:
 [127, 126, 125, 124, 123]
  Time: 2465.2448 miliseconds
useSetElements:
 [127 at [0][310], 127 at [0][277], 127 at [0][260], 127 at [0][81], 127 at [0][61]]
  Time: 1839.7323 miliseconds
```

Here the streams solution seems incredibly slow! The `Element` solution is the winner of the two `Set` solutions. I **expect** it's due to the fact that `Element`s are only created when they're needed for inserting into the `Set` and it's doing a straight up `int` comparison, while the other `Set` solution is unboxing every time the values are compared. I didn't further test my hypothesis though.

---

My curiosity of the other solutions in this thread got me testing out those as well. The solutions tested were:

- [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65374950/12695027) by [Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10819573/arvind-kumar-avinash)
- [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65380541/12695027) by [Anurag Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5825625/anurag-jain)
- [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65379921/12695027) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11263320/michael-chatiskatzi)

Running the tests on both the small and the large array:

```java
System.out.println("--- Testing performance ---");
timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("ArvindKumarAvinash: \n "
                                    + Arrays.toString(ArvindKumarAvinash(matrix,n))));
timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("AnuragJain: \n "
                                    + AnuragJain(matrix,n)));
timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("MichaelChatiskatzi: \n "
                                    + Arrays.toString(MichaelChatiskatzi(matrix,n))));
                                        
System.out.println();
System.out.println("--- Testing performance with largeMatrix---");
timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("ArvindKumarAvinash: \n "
                                    + Arrays.toString(ArvindKumarAvinash(largerMatrix,n))));
timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("AnuragJain: \n "
                                    + AnuragJain(largerMatrix,n)));
timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("MichaelChatiskatzi: \n "
                                    + Arrays.toString(MichaelChatiskatzi(largerMatrix,n))));
```

..gave these results:

```java
--- Testing performance ---
ArvindKumarAvinash:
 [25, 22, 19, 19, 18]
  Time: 0.9076 miliseconds
AnuragJain:
 [25, 22, 19, 19, 18]
  Time: 6.2277 miliseconds
MichaelChatiskatzi:
 [18, 19, 19, 22, 25]
  Time: 1.2204 miliseconds

--- Testing performance with largeMatrix---
ArvindKumarAvinash:
 [127, 127, 127, 127, 127]
  Time: 3381.1387 miliseconds
AnuragJain:
 [127, 127, 127, 127, 127]
  Time: 120244.7063 miliseconds
MichaelChatiskatzi:
 [127, 127, 127, 127, 127]
  Time: 51.4259 miliseconds
```

It seems that solutions using streams are not very performant at all. **Michael Chatiskatzi**'s solution is by far the better performant one.

#### All the code

If you want to run it yourself, here a complete class for copy'n'paste'n'run:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class GettingTheTopN {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int n = 5;
      int[][] matrix = {{16, -20, 22, 19}, 
                        { 2,   5,  6,  8},
                        {17,  25, 16, 19},
                        { 7,  18,  4, 17}};

      System.out.println("streamIt: \n "
                         + Arrays.toString(streamIt(matrix,n)));
      System.out.println("useSet: \n "
                         + useSet(matrix,n));
      System.out.println("useSetElements: \n "
                         + useSetElements(matrix,n));

      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("--- Testing performance ---");

      timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("streamIt: \n "
                                          + Arrays.toString(streamIt(matrix,n))));
      timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("useSet: \n "
                                          + useSet(matrix,n)));
      timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("useSetElements: \n "
                                          + useSetElements(matrix,n)));
      timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("ArvindKumarAvinash: \n "
                                          + Arrays.toString(ArvindKumarAvinash(matrix,n))));
      timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("AnuragJain: \n "
                                          + AnuragJain(matrix,n)));
      timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("MichaelChatiskatzi: \n "
                                          + Arrays.toString(MichaelChatiskatzi(matrix,n))));

      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("--- Testing performance with largeMatrix---");

      Random random = new Random();
      int[][] largerMatrix =
        IntStream.range(0,10000)                     // 10000 on the first dimension
                 .mapToObj(i -> random.ints(0,128)   // values between 0 and 128 (not included)
                                      .limit(10000)  // 10000 on the second dimension
                                      .toArray())    // make the second 1D arrays
                 .toArray(int[][]::new);             // put them into a 2D array

      timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("streamIt: \n "
                                          + Arrays.toString(streamIt(largerMatrix,n))));
      timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("useSet: \n "
                                          + useSet(largerMatrix,n)));
      timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("useSetElements: \n "
                                          + useSetElements(largerMatrix,n)));
      timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("ArvindKumarAvinash: \n "
                                          + Arrays.toString(ArvindKumarAvinash(largerMatrix,n))));
      timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("AnuragJain: \n "
                                          + AnuragJain(largerMatrix,n)));
      timeMethod(() -> System.out.println("MichaelChatiskatzi: \n "
                                          + Arrays.toString(MichaelChatiskatzi(largerMatrix,n))));
    }

    public static Integer[] streamIt(int[][] matrix, int n){
      Integer[] result = 
        Arrays.stream(matrix)                                         // stream the arrays
              // This is the same as using .flatMaptoInt(..) and then .boxed()
              .flatMap(a -> Arrays.stream(a)                          // stream the array in arrays
                                  .mapToObj(i -> Integer.valueOf(i))) // turn the ints into Integers
              .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())                      // sort by higest values
              .limit(n)                                               // only pick n
              .toArray(i -> new Integer[i]);                          // put then in Integer array
      return result;
    }

    public static Set<Integer> useSet(int[][] matrix, int n){
      TreeSet<Integer> max = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.<Integer>naturalOrder().reversed());
      for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
          // Keep adding values until there's n elements in the Set
          if (max.size() < n) { 
            max.add(matrix[i][j]);
          } else {
            // if the new value is higher than the lowest value
            //  ..and the new values isn't already there.
            if (max.last() < matrix[i][j] && !max.contains(matrix[i][j])) {
              max.pollLast();
              max.add(matrix[i][j]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return max;
    }

    public static Set<Element> useSetElements(int[][] matrix, int n){
      TreeSet<Element> maxElement = new TreeSet<>();
      for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
          if (maxElement.size() < n) {
            maxElement.add(new Element(matrix[i][j],i,j));
          } else {
            if (maxElement.last().value < matrix[i][j]) {
              maxElement.pollLast();
              maxElement.add(new Element(matrix[i][j],i,j));
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return maxElement;
    }

    // ----------------- Performance

    static void timeMethod(Runnable toRun){
      long start = System.nanoTime();
      try{
        toRun.run();
      } finally {
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("  Time: " + (end - start)/1.0e6 + " miliseconds");
      }
    }

    // [Answer to "How to find first 5 highest value in a two dimensional array?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65374950/12695027) by [Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10819573/arvind-kumar-avinash)
    static int[] ArvindKumarAvinash(int[][] matrix, int MAX_N) {
        // Find count as the total number of elements
        int count = 0, row, col;
        for (row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            count += matrix[row].length;
        }

        // Create flattened = new int[count] and fill it with all elements of matrix[][]
        int[] flattened = new int[count];
        int i = 0;
        for (row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
                flattened[i++] = matrix[row][col];
            }
        }

        // Create max = new int[MAX_N] to store maximum n numbers.
        // Also, create maxPos = new int[MAX_N] to store the position of the maximum numbers.
        int[] max = new int[MAX_N];
        int[] maxPos = new int[MAX_N];

        // Loop MAX_N times. In each iteration, assume flattened[0] is the largest number.
        for (i = 0; i < max.length; i++) {
            max[i] = flattened[0];

            for (int j = 1; j < flattened.length; j++) {
                // If flattened[j] >= max[i], check if the position, j has already been
                // processed. If not assign flattened[j] to max[i] and j to maxPos[i].
                if (flattened[j] >= max[i]) {
                    boolean posAlreadyProcessed = false;
                    for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
                        if (maxPos[k] == j) {
                            posAlreadyProcessed = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!posAlreadyProcessed) {
                        max[i] = flattened[j];
                        maxPos[i] = j;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return max;
        // System.out.println("Largest " + MAX_N + " values: " + Arrays.toString(max));
    }

    // [Answer to "How to find first 5 highest value in a two dimensional array?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65380541/12695027) by [Anurag Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5825625/anurag-jain)
    static List<Integer> AnuragJain(int[][] matrix, int n) {
      List<Integer> allVal = new ArrayList<>();

     for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
             allVal.add(matrix[i][j]);
         }
     }
      allVal = allVal.stream()
                     .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                     .limit(n).collect(Collectors.toList());
      return allVal;
      // System.out.println(allVal);
    }

    // [Answer to "How to find first 5 highest value in a two dimensional array?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65379921/12695027) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11263320/michael-chatiskatzi)
    static int[] MichaelChatiskatzi(int[][] matrix, int n) {
        // int[] highestNumbers = new int[5];
        int[] highestNumbers = new int[n];
        Arrays.fill(highestNumbers, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < matrix[row].length; column++) {
                int currentEntry = matrix[row][column];
                if (currentEntry > highestNumbers[0]) {
                    highestNumbers[0] = currentEntry;
                    Arrays.sort(highestNumbers);
                }
            }
        }
        return highestNumbers;
        // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(highestNumbers));
    }
}


// -------------------------------------------
// -------------------------------------------
class Element implements Comparable<Element> {
  final int value;
  final int x;
  final int y;

  static Comparator<Element> comparator = 
    Comparator.comparing((Element e) -> e.value)
              .thenComparing((Element e) -> e.x)
              .thenComparing((Element e) -> e.y)
              .reversed();

  Element(int value, int x, int y) {
    this.value = value;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  public int compareTo(Element that){
    return comparator.compare(this, that);
  }

  public String toString(){
    return value + " at [" + x + "][" + y + "]";
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is very impressive. A lot of effort and work went into it. That is awesome.

Comment: I still have a small question: Why do you use `arrayClone()` in addition to my approach? The matrix is never changed there or am I missing something :)

Comment: @MichaelChatiskatzi You're right. I was too quick. You don't modify the original matrix at all. Sorry about that! I've edited it out now :)

Answer (score 1):

Now that the question is open again, I will present my comment as an answer.

Instead of iterating over the same matrix multiple times I fill the `int[] highestNumbers` with `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, iterate over the matrix once, and replace the smallest entry of max each time the current integer is greater, by updating the first entry of `highestNumbers` and sort it.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = {
                {10, -5, 15},
                {8, 20, 12},
                {27, -3, 14},
                {7, 17, 4}};
        int[] highestNumbers = new int[5];
        Arrays.fill(highestNumbers, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < matrix[row].length; column++) {
                int currentEntry = matrix[row][column];
                if (currentEntry > highestNumbers[0]) {
                    highestNumbers[0] = currentEntry;
                    Arrays.sort(highestNumbers);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(highestNumbers));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[14, 15, 17, 20, 27]
```

Comment: I ran your code and compared it to mine and others. Yours is very performant.

Comment: @Scratte I really appreciate your comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With Java8 streams it can be done with this (one) line of code. It will leave the original matrix untouched.

```
Arrays.stream(matrix) // create a stream of the matrix
      .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream) //Reduce 2d matrix to 1d 
      .boxed() //Convert int to Integer so we can sort reversed order
      .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder()) //sort array in reversed order highest first
      .limit(5) //Limit stream to 5 entries, the five top results
      .forEach(System.out::println); //Print the result
```

Answer (score 0):

Without sorting array *itself*, you can make [`sorted`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-) the *stream* over this array. Or you can implement a kind of *selection sort* in descending order. These two code examples do the same thing - find the first 5 highest *distinct* values in 2D array, if they are present:

---

1. ```java
   int[][] arr = {
           {1, 4, 7, 7},
           {2, 5, 8, 3},
           {5, 5, 1, 2},
           {3, 6, 0, 9}};

   int[] max = Arrays.stream(arr)
           .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
           .boxed().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
           .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
           .distinct()
           .limit(5)
           .toArray();

   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(max)); // [9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
   ```

---

2. ```java
   int[][] arr = {
           {1, 4, 7, 7},
           {2, 5, 8, 3},
           {5, 5, 1, 2},
           {3, 6, 0, 9}};

   int[] max = new int[5];

   for (int m = 0; m < max.length; m++) {
       int prev_max = m > 0 ? max[m - 1] : Integer.MAX_VALUE;
       for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
               if (arr[i][j] > max[m] && prev_max > arr[i][j]) {
                   max[m] = arr[i][j];
               }
           }
       }
   }

   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(max)); // [9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
   ```

---

<sup>See also: [Selection sort of array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65351884/14838237)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use below way this will give you below benefits:

- Keeping very simple logic, As you want highest 5 values and you will not loose any index location/order for existing array,
- Using this you will get better performance,
- Clean Code.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] matrix = {
            {10, -5, 15},
            {8, 20, 12},
            {27, -3, 14},
            {7, 17, 4}};

    List<Integer> allVal = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            allVal.add(matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    allVal = allVal.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
            .limit(5)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(allVal);
}
```

Output:

```
[27, 20, 17, 15, 14]
```